# Why does my ImageMagick / Imagick setup always crash when I read from an SVG?

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I'm running ImageMagick 6.7.4-0 and Imagick 3.0.1.

I have all of the delegates necessary for SVG (output of `convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES` shows `bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jpeg jng jp2 lcms lqr openexr png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib`).

Here is some sample PHP code to convert a very simple SVG into a PNG:

```
$file = 'baseball.svg';
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage($file);
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
print $im->getImageBlob();
```

I get a 503 response from the server; PHP reports nothing and logs nothing. I have all php errors enabled, display errors enabled, log errors enabled, etc. I can convert from .png to .jpg and all of that just fine.

And an important note -- I was able to work with SVGs just fine for several months on this server, but I had to upgrade ImageMagick from 6.6.x to 6.7.x to get some bugs worked out in relation to text distortion. I first tried the latest release (6.7.4-10) but couldn't get **any** conversion to work, so I downgraded to 6.7.4-0 and all conversions **except for SVG** work again. I just can't sort this one out!

**Edit:** Running on Ubuntu 10.04. Server is Litespeed 4.0.10.

**Edit 2:** I have just discovered that this code -- **when run from the command line (`php test.php`)** -- actually does create the .png from the .svg perfectly, even though it reports "Segmentation fault". Running this script from the browser does not produce any file.

```
$file = 'baseball.svg';
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImage($file);
$im->setImageFormat("png32");

$fp = fopen(time() . '.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $im->getimageblob());
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're running linux - which distro?

Comment: Good question! Let me amend the main question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried ImageMagick 6.7.x along with every combo of Imagick versions, no luck (always segfaults, but command line PHP is able to create the file at least)

I tried ImageMagick 6.6.x along with every combo of Imagick versions, still no luck (always segfaults, command line PHP is not able to create anything).

I tried adding all required and suggested dependencies for ImageMagick, and yet, stil no luck.

I removed Imagick, uninstalled ImageMagick, and then ran `apt-get install libmagickcore3-extra imagemagick --fix-missing`. Then ran `pecl install imagick-3.0.1`.

**Voila, all working as expected**, *but back to where I was before I attempted to upgrade ImageMagick*. I cannot seem to get a self-compiled version of ImageMagick/Imagick fully working with SVGs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you don't have the actual RSVG *binary* package installed.

Comment: See Edit#2. Could that still be possible? Also, I was able to convert SVGs before I upgraded ImageMagick yesterday.

Comment: I just ran `apt-get install librsvg2-bin` and it turns out librsvg2-bin was not installed on the server. Doesn't seem to have any effect, however.

Tried to also install `librsvg2-2` and `librsvg2-dev` but already had newest versions. Then I installed `libxml2-dev` which I did _not_ have. Doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: @CharlieS: I unfortunately can't think of much else - I use Imagemagick (and Ghostscript) extensively and in a Debian environment (so, you know, close to Ubuntu), but I 1) stopped trying to use the horribly documented PHP extension a long time ago, and 2) downloaded and compiled from source both Imagemagick and Ghostscript.  I would highly recommend avoiding PHP's implementation of Imagemagick and just stick to making shell calls.  Imagemagick (by itself) has amazing documentation and a great community.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into Ghostscript. I had read (I believe on the imagemagick forums) that running a convert via a shell call was more intensive than using imagick. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: While I split the handler for huge images off to another server (modifying and rasterizing 100mb PDF files, for example), I thumbnail hundreds of very large images a day on a simple quad-core web server using shell commands and I haven't noticed any problems.